# Counting subsets of bipartite graph part which admit an induced perfect matching

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory, graph-algorithms, counting-complexity, matching

Given a bipartite graph $G=(U \sqcup V, E)$, count $U^\prime \subseteq U$ for which $\exists V^\prime \subseteq V$ such that the induced subgraph $G[U^\prime \sqcup V^\prime]$ contains a perfect matching.

---

I believe that this problem is at least **#P-hard**, but I can't find anything that states such.

I've found a similar [question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/10788/computational-complexity-of-counting-induced-subgraphs-which-admit-perfect-match) on cstheory which states that counting subsets of vertices on a general graph for which there is an induced perfect matching is #P-Complete. The difference between our questions is I consider $U^\prime$ unique whereas they consider $U^\prime \sqcup V^\prime$ unique.

An alternative expression of my question could be: count $U^\prime \subseteq U$ for which the induced subgraph $G[U^\prime \sqcup V]$ contains a (maximum, potentially imperfect) matching $M$ where $\lvert M \rvert = \lvert U^\prime \rvert$, i.e. every $u^\prime \in U^\prime$ is adjacent to some $m \in M$.